# Dynamically Scheduled Jobs with Quartz

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I implemented a Scheduled Job in Spring, I'm using Spring 3.1.1 with Hibernate and Struts2. The configuration works fine, but I want to change de cron dynamically, so I found several examples but I could not implement them, everywhere are different configurations, I only need to read cron values from the database instead of configuration file. Is this possible somehow?

My configuration now looks like that:

```
<!-- Scheduler Tasks -->
<bean name="statTask" class="com.bvc.spring.schedulers.MarketStatusJob"></bean>

<!-- Scheduler jobs -->
<bean id="statJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="statTask" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
</bean>

<!-- Cron Triggers -->
<bean id="statCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="statJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 12 1/1 * ? *"/>
</bean>

<!-- Triggers -->
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="statCronTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance for help guys.

Answer (score 0):

The possibly easiest approach would be, to subclass `CronTriggerBean` and implement database property resolution in an overridden `setCronExpression(..)` method, where you go to the database, fetch the desired cron, and call `super.setCronExpression(dbValue)`

An alternative, harder approach is to implement a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` that reads them from a database rather than a properties file. It may not be trivial, though. There is no support for that, because it is more customary to read the values from a properties file. Also note that you won't be able to change the cron dynamically during execution.

Comment: Point me please, where I need to implement this? My MarketStatusJob class have a metod execute(); where I'll write my code for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have statCronTrigger, need to implement quartz trigger in your main class
Job detail is fine.

```
    CronTrigger trigger = null;
    JobDetail jobD;


    //Load context
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("YOUR_CONTEXT_FILES.xml");

    //Setup JobDetail

    jobD = (JobDetail) context.getBean("statJobDetail");

    //Setup CronTrigger
    try {
        trigger = new CronTrigger();
        trigger.setName("AppTrigger");
        trigger.setGroup(jobD.getGroup());
        trigger.setJobName(jobD.getName());
        trigger.setJobGroup(jobD.getGroup());
        trigger.setCronExpression("*/10 * * * * ?");// you can read this from DB as well or any other configured string 

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Scheduler
try{

        Scheduler scheduler =  (Scheduler) context.getBean("Scheduler");
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobD, trigger);
```

You may add quartz scheduler bean in context

```
  <bean id="Scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"></bean>
```