# Dynamic scheduling of jobs with User inputs

Tags: spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have to implement four types of Scheduled jobs:
1.One Time job
2.Daily job
3.Weekly job
4.Monthly job.

And i am getting some user inputs for every type of job.
Here if i am taking example of Weekly jobs then parameters i will be getting from user will be:
Frequency:Weekly.
Repeat every:2 weeks or 3 weeks like that.
Repeat on:Sunday,Monday like that.
Start time:10:00 a.m.
Start date:10-07-2015.
End date:10-09-2017

As of now what ever input i am getting from user ,saving in a table as it is.

Now what complexity i am facing is how to schedule these four different types of jobs .

If i go with creating cron expressions for different inputs then how i will pass these cron expressions dynamically to scheduler .

Please help .
I appreciate it.Thanks

Comment: i also tried to refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066886/dynamically-scheduled-jobs-with-quartz

Comment: but in this too we can only once read from database at runtime but it wont be dynamic reading possible .

Comment: i can have N number of processes to be scheduled .

Comment: i was looking into this http://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/dynamic-job-scheduling-quartz-scheduler/ .